# How to display a list of categories and subcategories menu style with data returned from database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am trying to display a vertical menu(navigation menu) which has a set of categories and subcategories.

I am able to fetch data from database, But failing to place the subcategories under it's parent exactly.

**I am able to display category and its sub-categories. But i need the subcategories to be displayed only when mouse hover or clicked on Category.**
Here is the snapshot what i wanted to do

[image]

**Electronics** --> when clicked on Electronics it must show the list under Electronics category

**Automobiles** has no sub categories      *Not all categories have subcategories.

Here is my code:
**Model**:

```
    function getCategories()
{
    $this->db->select();
    $query=$this->db->get('ci_tbl_categories');
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            $result =$query->result_array();

            for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++)
            {
                $query1=$this->db->query("select * from ci_tbl_subcategory where cat_id='".$result[$i]['cat_id']."'");
                if($query1->num_rows() > 0)
                {
                $result[$i]['sub']=$query1->result_array();
                }
                else
                {
                $result[$i]['sub']=array();
                }
            }

            //print_r($result);
            return $result;
        }
        else
        {
            return $query->result_array();
        }

}
```

**Controller**:

```
            function categories()
    {
        $this->load->model('categories');

        $result['res'] = $this->categories->getCategories();

        //print_r($result['res']);
        $this->load->view('category',$result);

    }
```

**View**:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#main").click(function(){
    $("#sub").slideToggle("slow");
  // alert("clicked");

  });
});
</script>


     <body>
<div id="category" style="border-radius:5px; width:200px;background-color:#d2dbde; ">
<?php //echo count($res)."<br/>";?>
<div id="nav_head">Categories</div>

<?php for($a=0;$a<count($res);$a++)
{
//echo $row['cat_name']['subcat_name']."<br/>";
?><div id="main"><?php echo $res[$a]['cat_name'];?></div>
<?php
if(count($res[$a]['sub']) > 0)
{
?><div id="sub">
 <?php for($b=0;$b<count($res[$a]['sub']);$b++) {?>

<div id="subcat"><?php echo $res[$a]['sub'][$b]['subcat_name'];?></div>

<?php }?>
</div>
<?php }} ?>
</div>
</body>
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, creating `div`'s in a loop with a static id's won't work as you'll end up with multiple `div`'s with the same id. Try using class names.

```
<div class="main">

<div class="sub">
```

Then you should be able to detect the click/mouseover and show/hide the `sub`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".main").click(function(){
    $(this).next('.sub').slideToggle("slow");
  });

  $(".main").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).next(".sub").slideToggle("slow");
  }).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).next(".sub").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think 2 changes are require in your code.

1. In model replace '$i' with '$result[$i]['cat_id']'

   ```
   <?php
   for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++){
                   $query1=$this->db->query("select * from ci_tbl_subcategory 
                   where cat_id='".$result[$i]['cat_id']."'");
                   if($query1->num_rows() > 0)
                   {
                   $result[$result[$result[$i]['cat_id']]]['sub']=$query1->result_array();
                   }
                   else
                   {
                   $result[$result[$result[$i]['cat_id']]]['sub']=array();
                   }
               }
   ```

   ?>
2. In view file [$b] is not required you can get output directly using following code :

   `<?php echo $res[$a]['sub']['subcat_name'];?>`

Hope this will help you... :)

Comment: First of All Thank you very much. I tried your code but ran in to problems. It says Message: Undefined index: cat_id in  $result[$result[$result[$i]['cat_id']]['cat_id']]['sub']=$query1->result_array();

Comment: I have modified my answer in model file. Let me know if you have any issue... :)

Comment: It says illegal offset type. I think i forgot to tell you. I already displayed the content in my div what i need is it should show the subcateories when on clicked or mouse hover on category name